# Start an activity from a listview with searchbox

Tags: java, android, listview, search, android-listview

Im having trouble with my listview and search box. Searching works fine, except for the fact that it is case sensitive. However, my problem is, starting an activity right after clicking.
The start activity is based on the position of the text. Therefore, if I dont conduct any research the links work fine. Yet, if i research for specifics the listview works but the links are wrong, because they are based on the initial position of the listview and not sorted by categories.

```
    import greendroid.app.GDActivity;
import greendroid.widget.ActionBarItem;
import greendroid.widget.NormalActionBarItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class m_m_aeritalia extends GDActivity {
        EditText edittext;
        ListView listview;
        Button search;

        String[] text = { "(Lockheed) F-104S Starfighter",
                        "Aermecchi / EMBRAER AMX", "G-222" };

        int[] image = { R.drawable.tf1, R.drawable.tf7, R.drawable.ts26 };
        int textlength = 0;
        ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setActionBarContentView(R.layout.m_listgeneral);

                addActionBarItem(
                                getActionBar().newActionBarItem(NormalActionBarItem.class)
                                                .setDrawable(R.drawable.ic_title_back),
                                R.id.action_bar_back);

                edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
                listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, image));

                listview.setClickable(true);
                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                                if ("(Lockheed) F-104S Starfighter".equals(text[position])) {
                                        // code specific to 2nd list item
                                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                                                        mcomingsoon.class);
                                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                                }

                                if ("Aermecchi / EMBRAER AMX".equals(text[position])) {
                                        // code specific to 2nd list item
                                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                                                        mcomingsoon.class);
                                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                                }

                                if ("G-222".equals(text[position])) {
                                        // code specific to 2nd list item
                                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                                                        fa_f4.class);
                                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                                }

                        }

                });

                edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        }

                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                        int after) {

                        }

                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                        int count) {

                                textlength = edittext.getText().length();
                                text_sort.clear();
                                image_sort.clear();

                                for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                                        if (textlength <= text[i].length()) {
                                                if (text[i].indexOf(edittext.getText().toString()) != -1) {
                                                        text_sort.add(text[i]);
                                                        image_sort.add(image[i]);
                                                }
                                        }
                                }

                                listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, image_sort));

                        }
                });
        }

        class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                String[] data_text;
                int[] data_image;

                MyCustomAdapter() {

                }

                MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, int[] image) {
                        data_text = text;
                        data_image = image;
                }

                MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> text, ArrayList<Integer> image) {

                        data_text = new String[text.size()];
                        data_image = new int[image.size()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
                                data_text[i] = text.get(i);
                                data_image[i] = image.get(i);
                        }

                }

                public int getCount() {
                        return data_text.length;
                }

                public String getItem(int position) {
                        return null;
                }

                public long getItemId(int position) {
                        return position;
                }

                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View row;

                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

                        TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row
                                        .findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

                        textview.setText(data_text[position]);
                        imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

                        return (row);

                }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onHandleActionBarItemClick(ActionBarItem item, int position) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_bar_back:
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, mbymanufacturers.class));
                        break;

                }

                return true;

        }
```

Hope I made myself clear,
Any suggestions?

Thank You
Tiberio Bozotti

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't query the String array directy, but get the item from the Adapter.

Try this...

Create a custom private class to hold the String and integer value pair, such as:

```
private class DataPair { String text; int value; }
```

Then, instead of using your MyCustomAdapter, create an ArrayList of DataPair objects and assign it to an ArrayAdapter, such as:

```
new ArrayAdapter<DataPair>(this, R.layout.ListView01, new ArrayList<DataPair>);
```

Now, for getting your data, you only have to do:

```
getItem(position).text
```

or

```
getItem(position).value
```

In case of the setOnItemClickListener use:

```
((DataPair)listview.getAdapter().getItem(position)).text
```